# What capabilities did the Mark I Perceptron demonstrate?

Tags: history

The [Mark I Perceptron](https://digital.library.cornell.edu/catalog/ss:550351), developed by [Frank Rosenblatt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Rosenblatt) in 1958, was a pioneering supervised image classification learning system. Many articles explain the mathematics behind it, and its shortcomings, but without talking about what was actually demonstrated on it, that brought a huge amount of attention and funding for more than a decade (from 1958 to 1970).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Perceptron&oldid=1164725715) mentions this research briefly, but doesn't go into any detail:

> Although the perceptron initially seemed promising, it was quickly
> proved that perceptrons could not be trained to recognise many classes of patterns.

What kinds of image classification problems was the perceptron tested on, that generated such interest?

Comment: There's a fine wiki page about, plus countless web pages and publications your trusted search engine will deliver to answer such an unspecific question. Sounds like someone is not willing to do his homework?

Comment: @Raffzahn Sir, would you agree with me that it is usually better to give the benefit of doubt to students, rather than assuming laziness or stupidity? The Perceptron wikipedia page doesn't talk about the specific capabilities of Mark I at all. Not one sentence about what was demonstrated on Mark I, only its shortcomings.

Comment: @RiteshSingh We're not really suited for students doing research homework. (You can check some of my early questions on the religion sites, if you like – I think some of them avoided deletion, but none of them were very good.) Learning how to do research _yourself_, the old-fashioned way, is a really important skill: helping you develop that skill is probably the point of this homework.

Comment: If you come back with a little more information (e.g. what the Mark I Perceptron _actually was_), it might make a better Stack Exchange question; though it might be an [ai.se] question rather than a [retrocomputing.se] question. If you can't find _that_ information (and you can show where you've looked), that might make a good question for [retrocomputing.se].

Comment: IMHO the wiki page does quite well describe the Perceptron in great detail and what it was intended to provide, how it did that and what was reached - shortcomings are natural part of any result / the science gained. But if you already know that the Wiki page does not contain any information, you should at least be able to exactly specify what is missing, shouldn't you? Possibly after checking the extensive list of further links and references. So far the question does not show any basic research.

Comment: Not being able to show (what we call) "basic research" is usual for students. I know I was really bad at it, back in the day. But while this network is often _useful_ to students, it isn't _for_ students; helping you with this sort of thing is your teacher's job. ([Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20%5bresearch-process%5d%20is%3aquestion&searchOn=3) has a little advice; it's aimed at university level, but might help you anyway.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Sir, thank you for kindly trying to explain. I am not a formal student, having left formal education a decade ago. I meant that I was a novice to history of computing, and that experts should try to accommodate my curiosity instead of attacking it as laziness. The Wikipedia article (which I have read multiple times before asking this question) doesn't have even one line on what Mark I could do. I have tried to read many other articles on the Perceptron as well. I am only very curious about what could it do, that brought a huge amount of attention and funding. This is not a homework.

Comment: @Raffzahn Please forgive me if my question wasn't clear. I wanted to know what specific kind of image classification problems was the perceptron able to solve? Is such a sample of images available that it could or could not classify? I am editing the question now to make it more clear. I repeat sir, this question is just out of genuine curiosity and wonder. I am very interested to know what the simple single neuron could do in 1958.

Comment: @RiteshSingh We're not intending to attack you. (A lot of people think we are; if you can think of a better way we could explain this, please let us know!) Our site simply has quality requirements that a question must meet; one of them is that the question isn't _very basic_ (or, if it is, you show us that the answer isn't easy for non-experts to find). To me, the question seems clearly answered by the "Learning algorithm" section of that Wikipedia article you cited. (Btw, I'm not a 'sir'.)

Comment: Oh, you're actually asking about the _historical_ aspects? Hmm.

Comment: You don't have to keep adding small background details to the question; that's not very useful. I'll have a go at editing your question, and if I've made it say something different to what you're asking about, you can edit it again.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I understand. You are extraordinarily kind, thank you  I haven't come across your way of accommodation and understanding in general on SE. In my experience, SE has always, always been judgmental and harsh ("How are you asking something so basic and stupid and lazy"). To be completely honest with you, I have never asked without a basic search at the very least. I have always asked after I felt at least some difficulty in finding the information. However, I was almost always reprimanded, with rare exceptions.

Comment: @RiteshSingh Is that what you were trying to ask? (This question might be better for [hsm.se], but I _think_ it's on-topic here.)

Comment: @RiteshSingh Well, that Wiki article does explicit state what problems the Perceptron was to be acting on (arbitrary) as well as what was archived (linearly separable patterns) and what not (anything past that) - which is not only what that implementation told us but also the essential definition of what  single layer capabilities are - so it's not only explained, but also about the fundamental principles of that structure. It can't get more basic.

Comment: @Raffzahn It states the _category_ of problems, but I don't see any specific examples. Unless I'm missing something, “This machine was designed for image recognition” is as specific as that article gets.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Because that's the very essence. We are talking about the begin of a development. That's usually a time with high expectations and low results (like "we will have a chess program beating any grandmaster by 1960 at latest" :)). Cutting it down to specific areas is something that happens in any discipline only way later, after learning that the imagined solution is not a on shot kills all one, the problems being way more complex and more sophisticated, specialized solutions are needed. The very basic process of gaining knowledge at work. (Also note the links to detailed results)

Comment: @Raffzahn Regardless of how generally-applicable they thought their technology would be, they _did_ test on specific problems with specific datasets. I imagine an academic literature review might turn some of that up, but equally, this might be one of those "only answerable by anecdote" questions.

Comment: I didn't find the answer to the OP's question at that wiki page - or elsewhere for that matter.  I see discussions of single-layer NNs and separability and what they can and can't do, including "learning", and I see a really neat picture of a maze of what looks like wirewrap jumpers - which is cool because I thought the initial perceptron was strictly a thought experiment and never knew it had a hardware embodiement - but nothing of what it _demonstrated_ or _how_.  There's a picture of it looking at a "C" - did it recognize "C"s?  All letters of the alphabet?  White connected shapes? What?

Comment: ... Could it be rewired to recognize other shapes?  How much "learning" did it show?  Could it identify san serif "C"s as well as serif "C"s or distinguish between them over time?  This was a reasonable question; I kind of surprised at the negative reaction from some of this board's respected high-rep contributors.